# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 5, 5], expected input[256, 3, 256, 256] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, siamese-network

I am trying to run following code but getting an error:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class EmbeddingNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EmbeddingNet, self).__init__()
        self.convnet = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5), nn.PReLU(),
                                     nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2),
                                     nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5), nn.PReLU(),
                                     nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2))

        self.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(64 * 4 * 4, 256),
                                nn.PReLU(),
                                nn.Linear(256, 256),
                                nn.PReLU(),
                                nn.Linear(256, 2)
                                )

    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.convnet(x)
        output = output.view(output.size()[0], -1)
        output = self.fc(output)
        return output

    def get_embedding(self, x):
        return self.forward(x)


class EmbeddingNetL2(EmbeddingNet):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EmbeddingNetL2, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        output = super(EmbeddingNetL2, self).forward(x)
        output /= output.pow(2).sum(1, keepdim=True).sqrt()
        return output
   
    def get_embedding(self, x):
        return self.forward(x)'''enter code here
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't significantly change the question after it has been answered. Since you already asked a new question, I have reverted your edit for this one.

Comment: Okay. I am newbie to StackOverflow. Can you please answer the new error if possible. Why I am getting that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is very simple .Its saying instead of 1 channel you have given 3 channel images.

one change would be in this block

```
class EmbeddingNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(EmbeddingNet, self).__init__()
    self.convnet = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 5),  #instead of 1 i have made it 3
                                 nn.PReLU(),
                                 nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2),
                                 nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5), nn.PReLU(),
                                 nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2))

    self.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(64 * 4 * 4, 256),
                            nn.PReLU(),
                            nn.Linear(256, 256),
                            nn.PReLU(),
                            nn.Linear(256, 2)
                            )
```

EDIT to next error:
change to this

```
self.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(64 * 61 * 61, 256), #here is the change
                    nn.PReLU(),
                    nn.Linear(256, 256),
                    nn.PReLU(),
                    nn.Linear(256, 2)
                    )
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved the error, my kernel wasn't initialized so didn't pick the updated file. 
But I got another error. 
RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0

Comment: Can u paste the full error message @sharad and also input size of your image in dataloader.of possible post your full code

Comment: Hello @Prajot I have added scereenshot above. I have added print statement and the output are as below:
torch.Size([256, 3, 256, 256])
torch.Size([256, 64, 61, 61])
torch.Size([256, 238144])

Comment: i have edit the answer for your new error

Comment: @PrajotKuvalekar where did you take numbers for `(64 * 61 * 61, 256), #here is the change`. How to determine them? What magic numbers do they depend on?

Comment: @EgoPingvina Series on Conv & maxpool will reduce the dim of feature maps, u can check the formula to calculate the output dim of featuremaps on some blogs